# Acceptance rate no longer shown?

Tags: support, accept-rate

Is the acceptance rate no longer shown in every question of a user?

Or is that a temporary SE system bug?

Does that mean that the acceptance rate doesn't matter any more?

Comment: You're right. Now everything is different. I don't like change...

Comment: Well, there go half my contributions to m.se.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, for pointing this out and bringing it up. I noticed the same, and thought it was just a temporary bug.

Comment: By the way, Jeff Atwood disagreed with the decision and proposed to [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179). Interested Math.SE users should feel free to participate in the discussion there; it takes a few clicks to add a meta.SO account. (And the association bonus allows one to comment anywhere immediately.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The display of the accept rate was [recently disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951) after an extensive discussion with the explanation:

> Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown.
>
> We're still keeping track of it on the backend for various things, but the negative behavior its display encourages outweighs its benefits.

I do not think that the attitude that accepting answers is encouraged has changed in any way, the accept rate is just a number that is no longer visible on the user cards.

---

The list of [recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/) has more or less up to date information on changes to the software.

Comment: Good news. I was more than a little tired of reading the comments that this feature induced.

Comment: And there was much rejoicing. Now I can be more sure that when one of my answers is accepted, it's because it actually helped the asker, and not because somebody bullied him into going through his questions and accept a random answer to each (or the highest-voted one or whatever).